# How to update an object and redirect back to home page?

Tags: django

I'm building a website where you can upload photos with name. You can also edit the name and/or the photo after uploading it and I'm having trouble with the edit function.

This is my `views.py`

```
def edit(request, id):

    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=id)
    form = PhotoForm(instance=photo)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PhotoForm(data=request.POST, instance=photo)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context = {
                'obj' : form.instance
            }
            # I want it to redirect back to the upload page which i set as '' in urls.py
            return redirect('/')
    
    else:
        context ={
            'form':form
        }
        return render(request, "edit.html", context)
```

This is my `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',upload, name='upload_from'),
    path('edit/<int:id>', edit, name='edit_form'),
]
```

This is my `edit.html`

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main.css'%}">
</head>

<body>
    <h2> What do you want to change? </h2>
    <form id= 'edit_form' action="." method = 'POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'> {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    
<button type = 'submit'> Submit </button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error saying "Page not found" and the http in the browser shows up as: **http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/**
I'm assuming is not working because the browser is looking for edit/ with no id, therefore the page is not found,  but why is it not redirecting back to the upload form like I set it up to in the  `if request.method == 'POST'`

Comment: `/edit/` does not match any of your url paths so you get the 404, the `edit` view will not be called at all

Comment: `action="."` means to submit to the current directory. I assume because of that it posts the request to `/edit/`. As you want to post to the same page the best thing to do is **forego** the `action` attribute, i.e. your form tag should be `<form id= 'edit_form' method = 'POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>`

Comment: Also as a best practice in Django **always** end your url patterns in a trailing `/` (unless they are empty strings). By default Django will redirect any urls without a trailing slash to one with a trailing slash.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you so much, this worked! I didn't even noticed it. And thanks a lot for the tip too! I'm learning Django so I'm really sure what's the correct way to do things or what are good and bad habits, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def edit(request, id):
    ......
    return edit(request, id)
```

use the edit function presents the edit again.

or use redirect forward to show this edit:

```
return redirect('YOUR_APP_NAME:edit', id=id)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's best you remove the action attribute on the form tag.

Second, on your redirect, I'd rather you say...

```
return redirect('appname:edit', pk=pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your redirect you could use:
`return HTTPResponseRedirect(reverse, 'upload', kwargs = ['id':id]`